# How to construct the simplest time lapse slider with an action cam?

Tags: motor

I would like to motorize a simple slider, with a Action Cam / Gopro on top of this:
[enter link description here](https://goo.gl/TiZUvS)

I'm fairly newbie in Electronics, so sorry for silly question.

What can i do to pull the action cam sled? A simple dc motor (not servo) with a battery ?

What can else i need ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fo2hj6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) Simple fixed-speed drive. (b) Variable speed drive.*

- (a) Will run the motor at fixed speed until the limit switch is hit.
- (b) The LM317 is an adjustable voltage regulator. Speed is adjusted by R1. You could use a 10k pot if it's available but full speed will be reached before the end of rotation.